# Signout issue adf application in chrome browser Content Security Policy of your site blocks some resources

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, glassfish, oracle-adf

### Problem Summary

Signout issue adf application chrome Content Security Policy of your site blocks some resources

### Problem Description

I have an adf application with jdev12.2.1.4 which is deployed in glassfish 3.1.2.19 and using apache shiro for security.The problem is when i try to signout my application it is not exactly signing out and found no error in logs. When i tried the same in firefox , the application is redirecting without any issues . when tried with chrome issue occurs.
FYI, we are able to signout in chrome in mobile device without any issues. Also this issue occurs only when i call my application from apache. If i call my applicationby ip with port it works just fine in all browsers.
When we inspect the chrome browser on signout the following error is showing in console window
Refused to send form data to 'https://IP/support/faces/Main.jspx?Adf-Window-Id=w0&Adf-Page-Id=1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self' *.chainsys.com *.gstatic.com *.snowflakecomputing.com *.windows.net *.microsoftonline.com".
And in the issues window i find following errorContent Security Policy of your site blocks some resources
From the issues i have also tried to add csp filters and headers in web.xml. But its not fixing the issue.
Also when i check the url in firefox during signout afrredirect parameter is called and redirecting to login page but in chrome the following issue,
Refused to send form data to 'https://ip/support/faces/Main.jspx?Adf-Window-Id=w0&Adf-Page-Id=1' because it violates the following
Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self' *.chainsys.com *.gstatic.com *.snowflakecomputing.com *.windows.net *.microsoftonline.com".
It does not contain afrredirect but adfwinowid and page id.

The steps that we have taken for the issue findings are below.

1. We can able to logout the application(production) in firefox browser.
2. We can able to logout the application(production) in chrome browser in mobile.
3. We also able to logout the same url (production) in mobile device in chrome browser.
4. We are also able to logout in all the browsers for QA servers(including chrome) irrespective of devices such a slaptop or mobile.
5. Issue is only in production server and that too by calling with the apache setup
   by calling with apache.
   What i am saying is-
   5.a. Calling my application from one of the glassfish instances - http://ip/port/support/faces/login.jspx - Signout is happening without issues
   5.b. Calling my application from the apche such as - https://ip/support/faces/login.jspx or https://domainname/support/faces/login.jspx - Issue occurs only in this case

FYI, I have tested the same case in QA , even by calling from apache the qa application works fine.

Kindly help to resolve the chrome csp blocked issue as soon as possible.

I have added cspfilters in my web.xml filters but stilll the same issue.